# Is the Machine Gun or the Spur better in Hard Mode?

Tags: cave-story

I'm not sure which weapon to choose, the Spur or the Machine Gun.  I've checked all over the place and the opinions are differing for the weapon of choice in Cave Story (Hard Mode)

I know that Machine Gun gives the extra range, but should I stick with MG or Spur?  Which is more effective against bosses?

Concurrently I am in the Sand Zone, and still in the process of getting the dogs for Jenka, which means I can still trade the Polar Star for the MG.

Comment: This question will most likely be flagged as it is opinionated, which is specifically discouraged in the FAQ. Some shoot faster, some do more damage. There really is no right or wrong answer. Sorry. It honestly does depend on your play style and which you are better and more comfortable with. Just because a weapon is technically stronger (more damage per second and range or such) doesn't mean for as good/comfortable with it.

Comment: It's not opinionated, to a certain degree.  I'm asking which is more effective to fight bosses.  Like pros and cons.  That's all.

Comment: Well your title is not clear that that is your question for one (but I did read that in there... I'm not stupid...). And even then different people are more effective with different weapons.

Comment: Just so you can see, this website has many of the pro's and con's of each weapon and the stat's of each weapon here. [Cave-Story Weapons Guide](http://www.cavestory.org/info_weapons.php)

Comment: I know what the weapons do, it's just the question of which is more effective in a boss scenario where you only have 3 hp.

Comment: Well read more carefully as it says the missile launcher/super missile launcher is effective against bosses. But my honest and humble OPINION is that at that low hp you best get the longest range weapon as possible...

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't include the Snake in your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you're concerned with are bosses, I'd stick with the Spur. It's a fun gun and does the damage you want for bosses.

The Machine Gun is great but I use it mostly for the added mobility; being able to float to make tricky jumps/ect is extremely helpful in some situations and very fun in others. The MG takes apart normal enemies just fun but the Spur is better for single target damage. The MG can help you dodge during boss fights as well, but it's not always helpful.

For not taking hits the MG is probably better as you can (with skill) dodge certain boss attacks and keep a better distance; as a bonus you don't have to aim as carefully either, but your fights will be a bit longer.

As noted, the Rocket Launcher is probably the best against bosses, but you'll run out of rockets before killing later bosses, so you can't depend on it.

Comment: Much thanks! I'll go with the MG, so I can finally complete Hard Mode once and for all.

Comment: @JimmyChen I found it really helped some of the trickier platforming, I always found the last cave much harder than any of the boss fights.

Comment: MG will become obsolete on the last two areas (Hell 1 and Hell 2), seeing that exp will difficult to get, while the spur does not use exp to deal its max damage.

Comment: The Spur is the ultimate weapon. It says so, in-game (after getting the Spur, go back to the Labyrinth weapon shop and talk to Chaba, he'll tell you all about it)

Answer (score 2):

Spur is good and it's great for a big, high damage shot, but the Machine Gun is my pick. This may be controversial, but it's utility is absolutely S tier, and you can upgrade it's ammo refill with the turbocharger later on. It has a higher dps as well which is my main reason for choosing it over the Spur. With the Spur, as great as it is for bosses, you can do even more damage to them with the Sword and it has a very poor dps